# JavaScript String replace() Method not working for NewsAPI http response text

Tags: javascript, http

I'm using the [NewsApi](https://newsapi.org/) API as content for a Typing Tutor app, which requires replacing characters that are not easily inputted (specifically, `’`, `—`,`“`,`”`, which need to be replaced with `'`,`-`,`"`,`"`, respectively).

I suspect the strings coming through are somehow encoded because the javascript string.replace() function is not working on strings pulled directly from the HTTP responses - it only works if I copy-paste the relevant strings from the API responses in the browser network tools or from Postman.

### Code

(in practice the string is pulled from the NewsApi API but it is a difficult issue to replicate as the news headlines are always changing...)

```
var string = "you’re"
string =  string.replace(/’/,`'`)
console.log(string)
```

### Expected Output

This only happens when the string is copy-pasted from browser console or postman:

```
>>  you're
```

### Actual Output

```
>>  you’re
// note the apostrophe has a direction (not vertical) and
// therefore can't be easily typed
```

EDIT: there was a spurious space in the regex before the apostrophe. This was a typo in the question - not in the original codebase - and has now been fixed.

Comment: Remove the whitespace in the regular expression.

Comment: EDIT: there was a spurious space in the regex before the apostrophe. This was a typo in the question - not in the original codebase - and has now been fixed. The problem still remains :(

Comment: `"you’re".replace(/’/,`'`)` works well. Without more details or a [mcve], there is nothing we can help you with.